# Stuck on Elementary Exponentiation

Tags: exponentiation

I'm confused. Why is it that for a problem in the form of: $(2^{x+1})(2^{x-1})$ we get $2^{2x}$ instead of $4^{2x}$; Shouldn't we multiply the $2$s by each other..?

Similarly for a problem like: $(2^{x+1})(4^{x-1})$, why do we get $2^{3x-1}$ rather than $8^{2x}$?

And for $(3^{2x}/3^{x-1})$ we get $3^{x+1}$...shouldn't the $3$s cancel?

Comment: Some parentheses would help a lot... lack of them may even be why you're confused. [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for how to typeset common math expressions with MathJax, and [see here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for how to use Markdown formatting.

Comment: Lack of parentheses isn't why I'm confused

Comment: I tried to typeset your problem, could you check to make sure I didn't change the content?

Comment: Appreciate it, content is same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recall that $$\large a^b\cdot a^c = a^{b+ c}$$

$$\large \dfrac{a^b}{a^c} = a^{b - c}$$
$$\large \left(a^b\right)^c = a^{bc}$$

So, using these "laws of exponents", we have: $$\begin{align} (1)\quad \large 2^{(x + 1)}\cdot 2^{(x - 1)} & = \large 2^{(x + 1) + (x - 1)}\\ \\ & = \large 2^{2x}\end{align}$$
$$ $$
 $$\begin{align} (2)\quad \large 2^{x+1} \cdot 4^{x-1} & = \large 2^{x + 1} \cdot \left(2^2\right)^{(x-1)}\\ \\ &= \large \large 2^{x + 1} \cdot 2^{2(x-1)} \\ \\ & = \large 2^{(x+1) + 2(x-1)} \\ \\ & = \large 2^{3x - 1}\end{align}$$

Now, for the last question, I'll let you try to work that one out.

Comment: got it so we don't multiply the bases then if the bases are the same..

Comment: In general, we don't multiply bases...$2^a\cdot 3^b \neq 6^{a+b} $

Comment: What about for something like (3^x/2^y)^2...do we get 9^2x/4^2y?

Comment: $\left(\dfrac{3^x}{2^y}\right)^2 = \dfrac{3^x\cdot 3^x}{2^y\cdot 2^y} = \dfrac {3^{2x}}{2^{2y}} = \dfrac{9^x}{4^y}$

Comment: Nice Amy. I am glad I could catch you here before you leave for bed.

Comment: @amWhy: Argee with Babak - +1